# no value for a variable that is set in laravel

Tags: laravel, ternary

**1st code: **

```
       <div class="card-header">
        {{ isset($categories) ? 'Edit Category' : 'Create Category'}}
    </div>
```

**2cd code :**

```
            <label for="name">Name-->{{ isset($categories) ? $categories->Name : ''}}</label>
```

**im working on a categories table in laravel. the problem is when im creating a new category the 1st code goes -> 'Create Category', and the 2nd code goes : '  ' which it super good ! BUT when im editing a category the 1st code goes : 'edit category' and the 2nd code goes : '' instead of the value of $categories->name value . Can any one help !?**

Comment: is this a form? and where is `$categories` coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `!empty($categories)`, this may solve your problem.

**ISSET** checks the variable to see if it has been set. In other words, it checks to see if the variable is any value except NULL or not assigned a value, which means it will return true even if it's "".

**EMPTY** checks to see if a variable is empty. in your case "" will be considered as empty.

For more info  check

[this](http://www.geekgumbo.com/2010/12/18/php-the-difference-between-isset-and-empty/)